# Fields from textModulesData showing in details screen but not showing on first screen after saving the pass to google wallet (Tabular Format)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-wallet

I have just created generic class on google cloud and everything is empty and passing below json data to it as below

```
I have just created generic class on google cloud and everything is empty and passing below json data to it as below 

    "textModulesData": [
      {
        "id": "row11",
        "header": "Row11",
        "body": "11"
      },
      {
        "id": "row12",
        "header": "Row12",
        "body": "12"
      },
      {
        "id": "row13",
        "header": "Row13",
        "body": "13"
      }
    ]


Data showing in details screen as below screenshot but its useless.
```

[image]

```
 Why text fields not showing here in below screenshot?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your [GenericClass definition](https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/genericclass) not having a `classTemplateInfo` defined - which is how you tell Google Wallet how to display any other data in your object, including `textModulesData`.

I'll create a guide and drop it here later.